# Categories fibered in groupoids and the slice category

Tags: category-theory, groupoids, algebraic-stacks, slice-category

I read that one example of categories fibered in groupoids is the slice category $\mathcal{C}_{/x}\to \mathcal{C}$ where $x\in \mathcal{C}$ an object. But as the usual definition of slice category goes I don't see why the fiber over any point has to be a groupoid. If there is a map $y\to z$ over $x$ it doesn't have to be an isomorphism in general. So can someone clarify, am I just being dumb as usual or is this probably a typo or something? (FYI : The source is http://arxiv.org/abs/1708.08124v1)

Comment: In fact this is fibred in _sets_. There are no interesting morphisms between objects in the fibres.

Comment: @ZhenLin  But how is that possible, if $\mathcal{C}$ is abelian groups and $x=\Bbb{Z}$, then the fiber over $\Bbb{Z}$ is all group homomorphisms $\Bbb{Z}\to\Bbb{Z}$. Now take the map $f_n:\Bbb{Z}\to\Bbb{Z}$ by multiplication by $n$. Since $f_4$ and $f_2$ represent distinct objects in the fiber and there is a morphism between them because $f_2\circ f_2=f_4$. But clearly $f_2$ is not an isomorphism. What mistake am I making here?

Comment: Probably you are confusing objects and morphisms. The objects in the fibre are morphisms in the base. The morphisms in the fibre are…?

Answer (score 1):

As Zhen Lin said in comment, this is actually fibered in sets.

The fiber of $\pi: \mathcal C_{/x} \to \mathcal C$ at $y$ is the category whose objects are arrows $y \to x$ and whose morphisms from $f: y \to x$ to $g: y \to x$ are morphisms $k$ from $f$ to $g$ in $\mathcal C_{/x}$ such that $\pi(k) = \mathrm{id}_y$. Now remember that a morphism $k$ from $f$ to $g$ in $\mathcal C_{/x}$ is simply an arrow of $\mathcal C$ such that $f=gk$.

I let you conclude that the only arrows in the fiber at $y$ are identities.